# How To Parameterize Stored Procedures in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following hard coded Stored Procedure in Azure Data Factory

[image]

Can someone let me know how I can parameterize it? I need to be able select from a range of Stored Procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use script activity task to parameterize the stored procedures as well

You can also use dynamic content in SP activity as well :
[image]

examples :
SP activity
[image]

[image]

Updated:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @Nandan, thanks for reaching out, I'm not sure how to use a script activity to parmeterize. However, I have the available parameter "testlocation". I would like to if it's possible to somehow use that parameter in a stored procedure?

Comment: But script activity provides a greater flexibility w.r.t dynamic SPs with dynamic parameters

Comment: I have updated the ans to even parameterize the SP activity

Comment: Hi @Nandan, would you're parameter work with the following [inbound].[ImportFundManagers] ? If not, how would you assign [inbound].[ImportFundManagers] to your @pipeline().parameters.SPName ?

Comment: Basically, @Nandan, do I need to remove the square brackets [] ?

Comment: you can pass [inbound].[ImportFundManagers]  or even inbound.ImportFundManagers